# How to identify disks in RAID? Which controller / channel?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raid

I have m/b Asus
RAID 10 on Intel RAIDXpert2

Log says "medium error on controller 1 channel 1". Although 1 disk is offline I dont think it has anything to do with that message as it also says "repaired medium error" - how would it repair anything on an offline disk?

How to figure - how controller / channel number correlates with the disks?

What are those numbers near disk names 10, 11, 14? Are those the same as the controller/channel?

Does it mean 9YN164 had the medium error reported?

[image]

Comment: Disk 1 1 seems to have the serial number of ST2000DM001-9YN164.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel number correspond to actual connector. Look at the main board manual.
You can also look at the disk S/N: disk 1-1 has S/N Z1E09J1R as I can see on the screen dump you provide. That S/N is written on a sticker on top of the disk.